# show a message box containing a list of all files in a directory except one?

Tags: excel, vba, file, messagebox

I am trying to bring up a message box in excel showing a list of all the files in a directory like so:

```
 Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("S:\Tasks\Tenders\" & Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\*.*")
    StrFile = Dir
        MsgBox StrFile
```

the problem  have at the moment is this only shows one file out of a possible 20.

I am trying to get all the files in the folder listed in the message box like so:

```
File 1
File 2
File 3
etc
```

I also have a file called log.txt which I want to exclude from being listed.

Please can someone show me the best way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you should do it like this:

```
Dim StrFile As String, StrFiles as String
StrFile = Dir("S:\Tasks\Tenders\" & Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\*.*")

Do While StrFile <> ""
    If StrFile <> "log.txt" Then StrFiles = StrFiles & vbCrLf & StrFile
    StrFile = Dir
Loop

MsgBox StrFiles
```

Comment: thanks for this, this works great, but how would I be able to exclude my file 'log.txt' ?